# how to pass variables into a nested function in dply::across?

Tags: r, dplyr, nested-function, across

I am trying to calculate a rolling correlation across multiple columns in a data frame. I would like to use `dplyr::across`, but the variables (columnname) are not found:

```
df <- dplyr::tibble(
  "a" = runif(1000, min=-2, max=2),
  "b" = runif(1000, min=-2, max=2),
  "c" = runif(1000, min=-2, max=2),
  "d" = runif(1000, min=-2, max=2)
)

df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(
    .cols = c("c","d"),
# the correlation should always be calculated against "a"
    .fns = ~tibbletime::rollify(stats::cor(get("a"),.x), window = 100),
    .names = "{col}_corr"))
```

I get the error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`. i `..1 = dplyr::across(...)`. x `..1` must be a vector, not a function.

with any modification to the `.fns` formula I tried `.x` is not recognized.
Can you please help me how to pass the variable x into the nested function?

Comment: Do you have an example of what the output should look like? I'm not sure if I'm ending up with the right answer. I was finding it hard to combine the formula syntax of `rollify()` with the formula syntax of `across()`. But if I make a function `corr_roll()` outside of `across()` as shown in the `rollify()` Examples section, `cor_roll = tibbletime::rollify(~cor(.x, .y), window = 100)` and then use that within `across()`, `.fns = ~cor_roll(a, .x),`, it at least returns something.

Comment: OK, without making `corr_roll()` separately it is possible your function in `across()` could look like `.fns = ~tibbletime::rollify(~cor(.x, .y), window = 100)(a, .x)`. It appears to return the same thing as the two step process but the code seems a little difficult to follow. Still unsure if returns what you expect.

Comment: @aosmith you are awesome! :) That was exactly the hint I needed! The idea to define the variables separately after the second function, would not have come to me! Thanks for your quick help! Top!